# access permission problem for facebook using share kit in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sharekit

I integrated facebook app using sharekit by giving the FB Secret key and session key. It works fine previously. But Now, for the new user it does not ask allow permission , directly opens the FB web app.

Can anybody tell, what's the problem ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check cookie word in your code.After that Make clearcookies=YES.
I think currently your clearcookies set to nil.

Comment: @HCharli..thanks for reply. but, i didn't write any code for delete cookies . directly using sharekit . in that, there is the method for deletecookies in the FBSession class . that was working previously , but now facing problem.